# Android java updating certificate and private keys in Android KeyStore

Tags: java, android, keystore

I have a system that uses HTTPS client certificates to authenticate, but the certificates themselves are generated, according to the following process:

1. Client device generates a certificate (including public and private key)
2. Client device sends the public key to the server, which signs the public key, and returns it as a signed certificate
3. Client stores the certificate in a secure fashion, and then later on uses it as the HTTPS client certificate

We have this system working on iOS, and I'm trying to port across to android, but encountering a lot of problems with Android's poorly documented and confusing security API's.

My code goes roughly like this:

**Generating the certificate**

```
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEYSTORE);
keyStore.load(null);

Date startDate = new Date();
Date endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + FORTY_YEARS_IN_MILLISECONDS);

KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
        .setAlias(alias)
        .setKeySize(2048)
        .setKeyType(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA)
        .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + alias))
        .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.TEN)
        .setStartDate(startDate)
        .setEndDate(endDate)
        .build();

KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, ANDROID_KEYSTORE);
generator.initialize(spec);
KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair(); // this will put a certificate and key pair in the keyStore.
dumpKeyStore(keyStore);

byte[] entireKey = keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded();
// chop off first 24 bytes; the java key pair generator puts an object ID of  1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 RSA (RSA_SIGN) before the key which gets mangled when the server signs and sends back the certificate
byte[] publicKeyBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(entireKey, 24, entireKey.length);
```

`dumpKeyStore` is a utility method which iterates the keystore, calls `keyStore.getEntry` to get each entry and and just logs things.
At this point, it reports that there is a single entry with the given alias, and it is of type `KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry`. It has an associated certificate and public key which can be retrived from the `PrivateKeyEntry`.

**Sending to the server**

`publicKeyBytes` is sent to the server, which puts it as the public key for a new, signed x509 certificate, which is sent back in the response. I haven't put code in, it's just basic networking. The returned certificate loads and looks fine from what I can tell.

**Saving and associating the certificate**

I'm trying to put it into the keyStore with the same alias, so it (in theory) can be associated with the correct private key from earlier. My code thus far is like this:

```
KeyStore keyStore;
try {
    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEYSTORE);
    keyStore.load(null);
}catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException e) {
    Log.wtf(TAG, e);
    throw new FatalError(TAG, e);
}

CertificateFactory certificateFactory;
try {
    certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
} catch (CertificateException e) {
    Log.wtf(TAG, e);
    throw new FatalError(TAG, e);
}

Certificate cert = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(certificateFromServer));

// find the existing certificate, copy it's private key out, then replace the certificate with the one from the server but keeping the private key
try {
    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry existingPrivateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);

    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry newEntry = new KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry(existingPrivateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey(), new Certificate[]{ cert });
    keyStore.setEntry(alias, newEntry, null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.wtf(TAG, e);
    throw new FatalError(TAG, e);
}
dumpKeyStore(keyStore);
```

At this point, the final dumpKeyStore indicates that there is an entry with the correct alias, however it gets a "NoSuchAlgorithmException: Unknown key entry" exception thrown when it tries to call `keyStore.getEntry`

Is what I'm trying to do (replace a certificate but keep the private key) possible in android? If so, how might I do it? It seems like this isn't really working

Thanks

Orion

Answer (score 8):

As it turns out, I was doing the wrong thing. You don't need to replace or modify the certificates in the KeyStore, you just need to use a custom `KeyManager` when you initialize the `SSLContext` used by `HttpsURLConnection` and the KeyManager can pick whichever certificates or private keys you'd like.

This simplifies the KeyStore management greatly. My scenario is now

1. Generate a public/private key pair using `KeyPairGenerator` with an alias of `X`
2. Send the public key to the server which generates a new signed certificate from that public key, and and sends it back
3. Put this signed certificate in the KeyStore using `setCertificateEntry` with an alias of `X-Signed`

When I establish the `HttpsURLConnection`, it goes like this:

```
KeyStore androidKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(LocalKeyStore.ANDROID_KEYSTORE);
androidKeyStore.load(null);

X509Certificate signedClientCertificate = (X509Certificate)androidKeyStore.getCertificate("X-Signed");
KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)androidKeyStore.getEntry("X", null);

X509ExtendedKeyManager keyManager = new X509ExtendedKeyManager() {
    @Override
    public String chooseClientAlias(String[] keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket) {
        return clientCertificateAlias;
    }
    @Override
    public String chooseServerAlias(String keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket) {
        return null; // different if you're validating the server's cert
    }
    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String alias) {
        return new X509Certificate[] { signedClientCertificate };
    }
    @Override
    public String[] getClientAliases(String keyType, Principal[] issuers) {
        return new String[]{ "X" };
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getServerAliases(String keyType, Principal[] issuers) {
        return null; // different if you're validating server's cert
    }
    @Override
    public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String alias) {
        if(alias != clientCertificateAlias) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("X509ExtendedKeyManager is asking for privateKey with unknown alias %s. Expecting it to ask for %s", alias, clientCertificateAlias));
            return null;
        }
        return privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey();
    }
};

X509TrustManager trustServerCertificates = new X509TrustManager() {
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        // do nothing, this method doesn't get called
    }
    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) 
        // code to validate server's cert in here
    }
    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null; // any issuer
    }
};

m_sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
m_sslContext.init(new KeyManager[]{ keyManager }, new TrustManager[] { trustServerCertificates }, null);

// later on

conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
SSLContext sslContext = m_sslContext;

if(conn instanceof HttpsURLConnection && sslContext != null) {
    ((HttpsURLConnection)conn).setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
}
```

This is working well for me, and I can keep using `AndroidKeyStore` with it's per-app privacy and hardware-backed storage

Comment: This is a good solution. However, I think it would be better if you could replace the certificate associated with X.  I've filed a bug to fix that.

Comment: what is the value of clientCertificateAlias?

Comment: it should be "X"

Answer (score 2):

I am having similar issues with the native AndroidKeyStore. I cannot update certificate once it has been created with `generator.generateKeyPair()`

It appears that the current OpenSSL implementation of the Android key store is not yet fully complete. I looked for working sample for a while but could not find anything that would let me update existing certificate belonging to the `KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry` thus I have filed bug for this issue here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194955&q=keystore&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Meanwhile I would suggest to use "BKS" Bouncy Castle key store if you dont mind using third party cryptography provider.

**Update:**
Custom KeyManager may be a better workaround for use in mutual SSL situation where you can force to use one keystore alias for private key and another keystore alias for the certificate chain. However the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html) states you should be able to replace it:

> Generating a new PrivateKey requires that you also specify the initial
>   X.509 attributes that the self-signed certificate will have. You can
>   replace the certificate at a later time with a certificate signed by a
>   Certificate Authority.

Answer (score 0):

**This comment is not fully accurate and can be ignored**

The solution provided in the second post doesn't seem to protect the key securely the way it is expected from a [Hardware-backed Keystore](https://source.android.com/security/keystore) since `null` is passed as the third parameter(protoParam) to the `KeyStore.setEntry`:

```
    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry newEntry = new KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry(existingPrivateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey(), new Certificate[]{ cert });
    keyStore.setEntry(alias, newEntry, null);
```

As a result the key's raw material is accessible as shown in the code itself:

```
    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)androidKeyStore.getEntry("X", null);
```

I think the correct solution must take advantage of 
[KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder) to securely store the key and only perform cryptographic operation on it. I would very much appreciate if someone provides a sample code that uses client certificate protected by AndroidKeyStore in a TLS mutual authentication.

Comment: As per my answer above, the code that you reference with `keyStore.setEntry(alias, newEntry, null);` didn't end up working, and instead I create the key in the keystore, don't ever copy/move/set it, and use a custom KeyManager to select the right client certificate.

As far as I can tell this answer *does* use client certificates protected by AndroidKeyStore and it definitely does TLS mutual authentication

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I also achieved the mutual authentication with your code but in your example the keys were leaked from hardware-backed storage to the android framework/java application. Android internal storage that is private to each app can be used as well instead of key-store as the example does not benefit the security protection provided by AndroidKeyStore. One main purpose of Keystore is to perform cryptographic operations (sign, decrypt) with no access to the raw private key material. Would it be possible for you to share the code with us?

Comment: I did some testing and I think you are right. The only value that is leaked to the outside from privKey object is the modulus value that is supposed to be known.

Comment: thanks lots for verifying that! I wanted to go and test it to make sure it wasn't leaking keys but I never had the time.