# Android Ssl Handshake failed

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore

Based on solution from [Android java updating certificate and private keys in Android KeyStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771095/android-java-updating-certificate-and-private-keys-in-android-keystore)

im trying to connect with backend using server signed certificate

```
// csrRepository.keyPair() returning key pair (pub and private) from AndroidKeyStore
// certificateRepository.getCertificate(CERT_ALIAS) as X509Certificate returning certificate signed by server

val csrKeyPair = csrRepository.keyPair()

val clientCert = certificateRepository.getCertificate(CERT_ALIAS) as X509Certificate

val keyManager = object : X509KeyManager {
    override fun getClientAliases(keyType: String?, issuers: Array<out Principal>?): Array<String> {
        Timber.i("getClientAliases ")
        return arrayOf("csr_alias")
    }

    override fun chooseClientAlias(
        keyType: Array<out String>?,
        issuers: Array<out Principal>?,
        socket: Socket?
    ): String {
        Timber.i("chooseClientAlias ")
        return "csr_alias"
    }

    override fun getServerAliases(keyType: String?, issuers: Array<out Principal>?): Array<String>? {
        Timber.i("getServerAliases ")
        return null
    }

    override fun chooseServerAlias(
        keyType: String?,
        issuers: Array<out Principal>?,
        socket: Socket?
    ): String? {
        Timber.i("chooseServerAlias ")
        return null
    }

    override fun getCertificateChain(alias: String?): Array<X509Certificate> {
        Timber.i("getCertificateChain ")
        return arrayOf(clientCert)
    }

    override fun getPrivateKey(alias: String?): PrivateKey {
        Timber.i("getPrivateKey ")
        return csrKeyPair.private
    }
}

val trustServerCertificates: X509TrustManager = object : X509TrustManager {
    @Throws(CertificateException::class)
    override fun checkClientTrusted(chain: Array<X509Certificate>, authType: String) {
        Timber.i("checkClientTrusted ")
        // do nothing, this method doesn't get called
    }

    override fun checkServerTrusted(chain: Array<X509Certificate>, authType: String) {
        Timber.i("checkServerTrusted ")
        // code to validate server's cert in here
    }

    override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate> {
        Timber.i("getAcceptedIssuers ")
        return emptyArray() // any issuer
    }
}

val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
    .apply {
        init(arrayOf(keyManager), arrayOf(trustServerCertificates), null)
    }

val openConnection: HttpsURLConnection =
    URL(url).openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection

openConnection.sslSocketFactory = sslContext.socketFactory

openConnection.connect()
```

so far im still getting same error

```
W/CryptoUpcalls: Preferred provider doesn't support key:
    java.security.InvalidKeyException: Keystore operation failed
        at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:1362)
        at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:1402)
        at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54)
        at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:89)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:265)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:109)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2984)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2891)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2796)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:773)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1143)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1084)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.CryptoUpcalls.rsaOpWithPrivateKey(CryptoUpcalls.java:173)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.CryptoUpcalls.rsaSignDigestWithPrivateKey(CryptoUpcalls.java:132)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:387)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:226)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:196)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:153)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
        at xxx.yyy.zzz.feature.main.MainActivity$onCreate$2.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:171)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
     Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Incompatible digest
        at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:1292)
        at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:1402) 
        at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54) 
        at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:89) 
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:265) 
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:109) 
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2984) 
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2891) 
        at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2796) 
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:773) 
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1143) 
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1084) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.CryptoUpcalls.rsaOpWithPrivateKey(CryptoUpcalls.java:173) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.CryptoUpcalls.rsaSignDigestWithPrivateKey(CryptoUpcalls.java:132) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:387) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:226) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:196) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:153) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30) 
        at xxx.yyy.zzz.feature.main.MainActivity$onCreate$2.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:171) 
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33) 
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106) 
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571) 
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750) 
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678) 
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665) 
E/MainActivity$$special$$inlined$CoroutineExceptionHandler: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:288)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:196)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:153)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
        at xxx.yyy.zzz.feature.main.MainActivity$onCreate$2.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:171)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7cb92cf908: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:04000044:RSA routines:OPENSSL_internal:internal error (external/conscrypt/common/src/jni/main/cpp/conscrypt/native_crypto.cc:740 0x7cb0789e6b:0x00000000)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:387)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:226)
            ... 19 more
```

according to

> W/CryptoUpcalls: Preferred provider doesn't support key:

and

> Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Incompatible digest

i suppose i generate key pair in wrong way, but after mixing plant of different attributes im out of idea right now how to make connection running

this is my key generator class

```
class KeyPairGen constructor(
    private val provider: String
) {

    fun generate(alias: String) {
        val keyPairGenerator =
            KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, provider)

        val keyGenParameterSpec = buildKeyGenParameterSpec(alias)

        keyPairGenerator.initialize(keyGenParameterSpec)
        keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()
    }

    private fun buildKeyGenParameterSpec(alias: String) =
        KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY)
            .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
            .setKeySize(KEY_SIZE)
            .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
            .build()

    companion object {
        private const val KEY_SIZE = 2048
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read this issue thread, it may help you to solve your problem: https://github.com/google/conscrypt/issues/718

Comment: @Robert this is it, i did not mixed digest with encryption padding like there